# How can i add properties to a facebook application dialog?

Tags: facebook, properties, dialog

How can i add properties (related to the user data access) to a facebook application dialog? for example not only access his basic information, but also to access other personal properties?

Answer (score 1):

When you ask a user to authorize your application it includes all the basic user data, plus public data the user shares.

If you want any other [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) you need to ask for them while authenticating the user or later on when you need them.

In order to ask for them in the auth process use this tutorial: [Server-Side Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) and the [OAuth Dialog tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).

If you want to ask for more permissions after the user has already authorized your app you can do it in a very simple way using the [js sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log("user logged in, auth response: ", response.authResponse);
        FB.api("/me/permissions", function(res) {
            console.log("permissions: ", res);
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.");
    }
 }, { scope: "email,publish_stream" });
```